# Can't save panel with controls to bitmap

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have been googling my behind off all morning trying to figure this out.

I have a panel with multiple labels, a picturebox and background image. I want to save this whole panel to an bitmap for printing, however, it only draws the panel and background image. None of my labels or the picture box is being draw.

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(jobcard.Panel1.Width, jobcard.Panel1.Height)
    jobcard.Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        bmp.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Anyone know what could cause this? P.S, I am using Visual Studio express 2012

EDIT : I got this working partly thanks to the help of Mou below.
I forgot to show the form before I tried to save the panel to the bitmap. The form is hidden so I didn't really notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width,panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.Bounds);
bmp.Save(@"C:\Temp\Test.bmp");
```

got the tips from this url **[How can I save a Panel in my form as a picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738054/how-can-i-save-a-panel-in-my-form-as-a-picture)**

i test it and it worked fine. here is the image of my panel which i generated programmatically. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just tried this with the same results, however, I saw on the link you gave me that DrawToBitmap is sort of unsupported after .net framework 4 and I am using .net framework 4.5. I am going to try changing my framework version and will post the results

Comment: Could it be an issue with my panel being on another form?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Turns out I forgot to show the form containing the panel before saving it. The form is hidden so I didn't really notice *facepalm*